# Convert Autofac Open Generic Interface Registration to DryIoc Registration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, dryioc

I want to register a mediator Im using from github, which provides a [sample](https://github.com/dasiths/SimpleMediator/blob/master/Samples/SimpleMediator.Samples.Shared/Helpers/AutofacHelper.cs) for registering it using Autofac.

I think my problem lies with this Autofac line:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IMessageHandler<,>))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

I'm not 100% sure  what the line of code does,`AsClosedTypesOf` to be more specific.

I tried to translate it to DryIoc as:

```
container.RegisterMany(
    new Type[] { typeof(IMessageHandler<,>) },
    serviceTypeCondition: s => s.IsInterface, 
    setup: Setup.With(openResolutionScope: true));
```

But I get the following error:

> DryIoc.ContainerException: 'Registering abstract implementation type
>   SimpleMediator.Core.IMessageHandler<,> when it is should be concrete.
>   Also there is not FactoryMethod to use instead.'

This is my registration code so far:

```
        container.RegisterMany(
            new Type[] { typeof(IMessageHandler<,>) },
            serviceTypeCondition: s => s.IsInterface, 
            setup: Setup.With(openResolutionScope: true));

        //var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => !a.IsDynamic);
        container.RegisterDelegate<ServiceFactoryDelegate>(c => t =>
        {
            return c.Resolve(t);
        });

        container.RegisterMany<ServiceFactory>();
        container.RegisterMany<Mediator>();
        container.RegisterMany(new Type[] { typeof(MessageProcessor<,>) });

        container.Register<IService1, Service1>(Reuse.Singleton);
        container.Register<IService2, Service2>(Reuse.Singleton);

        var service1 = container.Resolve<IService1>();
        var service2 = container.Resolve<IService2>();

        service1.GetDevice("asdf");
```

Without using RegisterMany for the IMessageHandler interface the program encounters the error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'No handler of signature IMessageHandler`2
>   was found for DeviceEventMessage Arg_ParamName_Name'

Basically what I understand is that I need to register the message handlers I have defined, which inherit from `IMessageHandler<,>`

Mediator defines IMessageHandler as such:

```
public interface IEventHandler<in TEvent>
    : IMessageHandler<TEvent, Unit> where TEvent : IMessage<Unit>
{
}
```

And I implement it in the service:

```
public class Service2 : IService2, IEventHandler<DeviceEventMessage>
{
    public async Task<Unit> HandleAsync(
        DeviceEventMessage message,
        IMediationContext mediationContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Unit.Result;
    }
}
```

Where service1 actually calls the mediator in `GetDevice("asdf")` which requires the handler to be resolved.

How would I register classes implementing `IMessageHandler<,>` in *DryIoc*?

Comment: Btw, did you now about DryIoc.Messages namespace https://www.fuget.org/packages/DryIoc.dll/4.0.5/lib/netstandard2.0/DryIoc.dll/DryIoc.Messages

Comment: There is also a DryIoc.Syntax.Autofac.dll package: https://www.fuget.org/packages/DryIoc.Syntax.Autofac.dll

Comment: @dadhi I did not know about the messages namespace,  new to using a mediator and services so tried using one from a learning perspective.  I may drop it for the DryIoc one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update: fixed the working sample

Added `s.GetGenericDefinitionOrNull()` in `serviceTypeCondition`

### Answer

The exception is exactly about the problem here:

```cs
container.RegisterMany(
    new Type[] { typeof(IMessageHandler<,>) },
    serviceTypeCondition: s => s.IsInterface,
    setup: Setup.With(openResolutionScope: true));
```

This `RegisterMany` overload expects the first argument to be a collection of concrete Implementation types.

For your case you probably need something like this instead:

```cs
container.RegisterMany(
    new[] { typeof(Service1).GetAssembly() },
    serviceTypeCondition: s => s.GetGenericDefinitionOrNull() == typeof(IMessageHandler<,>));
```

Btw, not sure what is the reason for `openResolutionScope: true`.

Comment: Can't remember why I added openResolutionScope: true, wrote it in a rush. changed the line to this and the new [error](https://pastebin.com/WVWUg1Jd)

Comment: I have fixed the sample - check the update and the working sample. Here is the live code sample for reference: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lM6npy